# What does "msLoadMap not incl." mean?

Tags: mapserver, windows-8, cygwin

I receive "mapserv request processing time (msLoadMap not incl.)" in my ms_error.log, but no idea what that means, is that an error or the normal behavior of MapServer?

It appears regardless the layer is point, line or polygon:

Point example:

```
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:34 2014].499867 CGI Request 1 on process 7956
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:34 2014].505409 msDrawMap(): rendering using outputformat named png (AGG/PNG).
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:35 2014].480974 msDrawMap(): Layer 0 (Boreholes), 0.976s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:35 2014].481018 msDrawMap(): Drawing Label Cache, 0.000s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:35 2014].481032 msDrawMap() total time: 0.980s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:35 2014].573357 msSaveImage(stdout) total time: 0.092s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:35 2014].574595 mapserv request processing time (msLoadMap not incl.): 1.075s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:35 2014].574638 msFreeMap(): freeing map at 0x80012a68.
```

Line example:

```
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:36 2014].69162 CGI Request 1 on process 8928
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:36 2014].84536 msDrawMap(): rendering using outputformat named png (AGG/PNG).
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:37 2014].649376 msDrawMap(): Layer 7 (Seismic_profiles), 1.565s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:37 2014].649442 msDrawMap(): Drawing Label Cache, 0.000s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:37 2014].649455 msDrawMap() total time: 1.579s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:37 2014].706250 msSaveImage(stdout) total time: 0.057s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:37 2014].707153 mapserv request processing time (msLoadMap not incl.): 1.638s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:37 2014].707185 msFreeMap(): freeing map at 0x80012a80.
```

Polygon example:

```
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:36 2014].1015 CGI Request 1 on process 4152
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:36 2014].6791 msDrawMap(): rendering using outputformat named png (AGG/PNG).
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:36 2014].245940 msDrawMap(): Layer 8 (Forearc_basins), 0.239s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:36 2014].245976 msDrawMap(): Drawing Label Cache, 0.000s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:36 2014].245986 msDrawMap() total time: 0.244s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:36 2014].297990 msSaveImage(stdout) total time: 0.052s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:36 2014].299173 mapserv request processing time (msLoadMap not incl.): 0.298s
[Mon Oct 27 07:56:36 2014].299201 msFreeMap(): freeing map at 0x80012a70.
```

Does "msLoadMap not incl." represent an error or a bottleneck problem because of cygwin?

OS:
win8.1 i5 (1.6GHz,8GB RAM), mapserver under cygwin

$ mapserv -v
MapServer version 6.4.1 OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=SHAPEFILE

$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.3-WOW64 gery 1.7.32(0.274/5/3) 2014-08-13 23:03 i686 Cygwin

Answer (score 2):

The output you are seeing is a result of the [DEBUG](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/map.html) (scroll down a little) statement in the mapfile.

Specifically, *msLoadMap not incl.* means that the time displayed on the same line after the colon is the time taken to process the request (i.e.: the time spent reading data from shapefiles, or databases, assembling symbology, rendering and then output), less the the mapfile parsing time.

The time required to parse (complex) mapfiles can be significant, hence the clause. You should find a separate line in the log file reporting the mapfile parsing time.

Comment: thanks for that, I'll take a look at the log file again, I don't remember a line reporting the mapfile parsing time, I have debug 5, it should be there then.

Comment: well, after checking I didnt find the line poiting to a mapfile parsing time, is that normal? what should I read from that specific line? I only got info about my layers

Comment: The line should report: *msLoadMap(): 0.3s* and requires debug >=2

Comment: I have debug=5 but that line doesnt appear, is it possible to track down that?

Comment: I just tried with debug 2 and 3 and nothing, that message is not there, what would it be wrong?

Comment: sorry for these several messages, but I was wondering if this lack of msLoadMap() message output causes my app to keep loading something that never succeeds, is there a way to figure that out?